# Do I need to recompile LESS to upgrade Font Awesome icons?

Tags: css, less, font-awesome

I'm very confused about LESS and in particular, the Font Awesome local files in a template I'm using.

I apparently have Font Awesome 4.3 and I've just downloaded 4.7. Of the files common to my project and the downloaded zip file, I'v overwritten the fonts and the less folders. Shouldn't that be enough to have my project use the latest icon set? - It's not as the old icons are working, but the new ones are not.

If I'm not recompiling less (do I even have to???), what else would I need to look for to get the new icons working?

**EDIT:**

In the main css file for the template, I've found some code related to Font Awesome:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('dev-plugins/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
  src: url('dev-plugins/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('dev-plugins/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'), url('dev-plugins/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'), url('dev-plugins/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'), url('dev-plugins/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

In that same file is reference to the FA icons - example:

```
.fa-times-circle-o:before {
  content: "\f05c";
}
.fa-check-circle-o:before {
  content: "\f05d";
}
```

So am now assuming my whole template needs recompiling?

Comment: How are you importing Font Awesome? Can you post some code?

Comment: To be honest, I can't actually tell how this purchased template initiates font-awesome. I'm guessing it does so in it's main css file (if that's even possible) - any tips on what to look for?

Comment: if you're using a task runner (eg gulp, grunt) to compile your less into css, you will need to recompile your less into css

Comment: can you post a link to the template? perhaps that might shed some light

Comment: If you don't really know how it's being imported then you don't really have a specific coding question, you have a vague issue.

Comment: True. Re the template, here's a demo http://aqvatarius.com/themes/intuitive/

Comment: If you update fontawesome files, make sure to clear your cache. Sounds too easy but it's a known issue with font files.

Comment: Judging by that example, the fontawesome files are embedded in your main `style.css` file, all 22K lines of it!. If you want to keep it that way, then the answer is **Yes**, you do need to recompile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've worked it out by doing the following:

1. access the source files for the template
2. replace the Font Awesome LESS files with the latest version from their zip download
3. replace the Font Awesome font files with the latest
4. with the new files in place, re compile the main CSS LESS file
5. overwrite the outputted CSS with the one in my project

I'm using using Windows so I used WinLess to compile the LESS file.

So the answer to my question is: yes - I did need to recompile some LESS because the Font Awesome details are embedded (for reasons beyond me) in the main CSS file.